# how to convert the passed in price value to cents before saving to database?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have create action that will create a karaoke object.

```
  def create
    @user = current_user
    @karaoke = @user.karaokes.build(karaoke_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @karaoke.save
        format.html { redirect_to @karaoke, notice: 'Karaoke was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @karaoke }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @karaoke.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

i have allowed the following parameters to bind

```
# Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
def karaoke_params
  params.require(:karaoke).permit(:name, :audio, :price)
end
```

Now what i want to do is in database the price field is of type integers because i am saving money as cents in database. So, in create action, before saving the user parameter for price, i want to multiply by 100 to convert it to cents. How can i multiply the passed in price form value by 100 and assign it to price field of Karaoke object? I appreciate any help! Thanks!

The form to accept the karaoke parameters are as follows

```
<%= form_for(@karaoke) do |f| %>
  <% if @karaoke.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@karaoke.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this karaoke from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @karaoke.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
        <li><%= message %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :name %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
  </div>


  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :price %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :price %>
  </div>


  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :audio %><br>
    <%= f.file_field :audio %>
  </div>


  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: One red flag in your process is you're allowing the front end to tell the back end what prices are. You should ideally be storing prices on the back end, representing them to the front end and then retrieving them again on form submission based on the product id or something. Never trust the front end.

Comment: @OneNeptune You are right but I think this end-user defined price for a Karaoke is a feature OP wants (because we see a label & text_field tags in the form).

Comment: You can change a value before saving to db using the callback before_save :convert_price in your model but than the value in frontend shows in cents unless you convert it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can rewrite the setter for `price` in the `Karaoke` model in order to convert any `Float` into `Integer`:

```
def price=(value)
  value = (value * 100).to_i if value.kind_of?(Float)
  super(value)
end
```

So now every time you pass a Float for the price of a Karaoke, it will be multiplied by 100 and converted to an Integer.

Answer (score 0):

If what you want is to convert the price passed in from the controller to an Integer (or a float in your case) when you save it to the database, you can use money-rails gem:

https://github.com/RubyMoney/money-rails